# MYSQL query to find partial matches in a string with delimiters

Tags: python, mysql

I have this table :

[image]

And i have this string in python **which can change** as it's a result of another previous query.

So the string could be either

```
string_1 = str(;123;131415;)
```

or

```
string_1 = str(;456;123;)
```

or

```
string_1 = str(;789;)
```

and so on ...

I'm searching for a query to compare each number between the `";"` delimiters in `string_1` and search for a match in `my_table` with `RLIKE`

Something like :

```
"SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE company_members_id RLIKE'" each numbers between ;; in string_1 "' "
```

It should return row 1 (match with ;123;) and row 2 (match with ;131415;)

Thanks

Comment: Sorry that edit doesn't explain much, what can change exactly?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your string in python and then iterate and do simple `WHERE string LIKE '%;{string here};%'`

So you end up doing:

`WHERE string LIKE '%;123;%'`

and

`WHERE string LIKE '%;131415;%'`

Or save the `string LIKE '%;131415;%'` as strings in python then join them with `' or '.join(like_statements)`

Don't complicate things.

You could also consider refractoring the database to have something like:

| ID | member |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 456 |
| 1 | 789 |
| 2 | 11112 |
| 2 | 131415 |

Maybe you're looking for

`RLIKE ';(123|131415);'`

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that the string is not always the same. It depends on a previous MYSQL query result ... I'll update my question

Comment: updated answer with another solution

Comment: Thanks RLIKE ';(123|131415);'  solve the problem :-)